# Microsoft Visual cannot add tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I´m new at Visual Studio C++ and maybe I´m asking a very trivial question. I have a project/application but I have to add a few new features to it. When I open the project in MVS and in "dialog" folder there are windows (or dialogs?) used by application and I can modify them but I´m not allowed to add components/tools that I really need. I have only Dialog editor tools unlocked. I can compile an run application but When I try to add a form to project I´ll see a message:

> You are adding a CLR component to a native project. Your project will be converted to have Common language runtime support.

I´ve googled some information about .NET forms and windows dialogs, but I do not know what to do next. If I choose "yes" (convert project) I cannot compile it anymore.
What can I do if I would like to use a ZedGraph controll to plot graphs from data in this app?

Comment: If this is MFC I don't think it will automatically convert to C#

Answer (score 2):

The C# GUI tools are different to the C++ tools (like MFC).

When you try to add C# tools to a C++ project the IDE warns you "You are adding a CLR component..."

Depending on which IDE you are using, when you bring up the resource view (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cfawwc.aspx) e.g. with `ctrl + shift + E` you should be able to find the existing dialogs and double click to edit them.

It seems that ZedGraph is a C# library (from the [docs](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/index.html)), so you will have to convert into a C# project in order to use it, which will not be straightforward, or use a suitable C++ one.

Comment: I have found this article, that seems maybe to be a solution. But I´m not familiar with the part where it´s discussed about StdAfx.h. I´m not sure how to deal with precompiled headers. Can I ask you to explain me that?

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2008/09/03/extending-a-native-c-project-with-managed-code.aspx

Comment: Contact Kate Gregory directly - she knows her stuff. If you wish to ask a new question, aska  new question. A precompiled header contains things that don't change very often so they can be, well, pre-compiled.

Comment: BTW - What you are reading won't help you mix C# and C++ GUIs.